# Wrap certain word with <span> using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following `div`:

```
<div id="query" style="width:500px; height:200px;border:1px solid black"
 spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true"></div>​
```

where Clients can write their `SQL` queries.  What I was trying to do is wrap words the client enters right after hitting <kbd>Space</kbd> with a `span` and give this span a certain `class` according to the word typed:

*example*

If the client types `select` i need to wrap this select word like this in the div:

```
<span class='select'> SELECT </span> <span> emp_name </span>
```

CSS

```
.select{color:blue ;text-transform:uppercase;}
```

It is something very similar to what `jsFiddle` does. How can i achieve this?

Here is what i have tried so far : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esu7A/1/)

```
$(function(){
    $('div').focus() ;
    $('div').keyup(function(e){
        //console.log(e.keyCode) ;
        if(e.keyCode == 32){
            var txt = $('div').text() ;
            var x = 'SELECT' ;
            $('div:contains("'+x+'")').wrap("<span style='color:blue ;
      text-transform:uppercase;'>") ;
            if(txt == 'SELECT'){
                console.log('found') ; // why This Doesn't do any thing  ?
            }

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a proof of concept with some modifications from what you originally had. See below,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/cgy69/

```
$(function() {
    $('div').focus();
    var x = ['SELECT', 'WHERE', 'FROM'];
    $('div').keyup(function(e) {
        //console.log(e.keyCode) ;
        if (e.keyCode == 32) {

            //using .text() remove prev span inserts
            var text = $.trim($(this).text()).split(' ');            
            $.each(text, function(i, v) {
                $.each(x, function(j, xv) {
                    if (v.toUpperCase() === xv) {
                        text[i] = '<span style="color: blue; text-transform: uppercase;">' + v + '</span>';    
                    }                                        
                });
            });

            $(this).html(text.join(' ') + '&nbsp;');

            setEndOfContenteditable(this);
        }
    });

    function setEndOfContenteditable(contentEditableElement) {
        var range, selection;
        if (document.createRange) //Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
        {
            range = document.createRange(); //Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
            range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement); //Select the entire contents of the element with the range
            range.collapse(false); //collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
            selection = window.getSelection(); //get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
            selection.removeAllRanges(); //remove any selections already made
            selection.addRange(range); //make the range you have just created the visible selection
        }
        else if (document.selection) //IE 8 and lower
        {
            range = document.body.createTextRange(); //Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
            range.moveToElementText(contentEditableElement); //Select the entire contents of the element with the range
            range.collapse(false); //collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
            range.select(); //Select the range (make it the visible selection
        }
    }
});
```

You going to extend this further to handle

1. <s>Backspace</s>
2. <s>HTML contents from previous inserts</s>
3. <s>Cursor position</s> Partially done, editing in the middle would still mess up the caret.

and more..

Comment: thanks .. look good but why does it focus at the beginning of all the span after firing ?

Comment: @MinaGabriel The caret goes to beginning after you change the value of textarea using a script. you can fix this by getting the caret position before update and set it after update..

Comment: Step two: prevent the caret from jumping.

Comment: @MinaGabriel See this http://blog.vishalon.net/index.php/javascript-getting-and-setting-caret-position-in-textarea/ for setting/getting caret position

Comment: that was really smart of you dude

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a `contenteditable` element we can replace the markup as we need by operating directly on its `innerHtml`:

```
$('#query-container').on('keyup', function(e){
  var $this = $(this);
  //(?!\<\/b\>) negative lookahead is used so that anything already wrapped
  //into a markup tag would not get wrapped again
  $this.html($this.html().replace(/(SELECT|UPDATE|DELETE)(?!\<\/b\>)/gi, '<b>$1</b>'));
  setEndOfContenteditable(this);
});
```

IMO this is a more readable option. Add the rangeselect method from the previous answer and we have [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/tFnzG/)